# How to insert TextNode after a specific node.

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument, nodes

I have a paragraph:

```
<p>
   This is a test <xref>1</xref> in the XML <xref>2</xref> bla bla bla....
</p>
```

I would like to insert `]` after the `xref` node.

For that, I am using the following code:

```
$refs = $paragraph->getElementsByTagName("xref");

foreach ($refs as $key=>$ref) {
   $squareBracket = $dom_input->createTextNode("]");
   $paragraph->appendChild($squareBracket);
}
```

But this is adding the `]` at the end of the paragraph.

Is there any function as `insertBefore` but to insert after?

Comment: No, this is not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
$squareBracket = $dom_input->createTextNode("]");
$paragraph->insertBefore($squareBracket, $ref->nextSibling);
```

We have to use nextSibling on the selected node.